# Drop down menu over mathjax formulas

Tags: javascript, css, mathjax

The code below creates a drop-down menu over mathjax formulas. Sometimes when I move the mouse cursor to menu elements, the menu disappears. More often if I move the cursor slowly. So, I cannot select any menu elements.

Here's the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>
    .dropbtn {
      background-color: #4CAF50;
      color: white;
      padding: 16px;
      font-size: 16px;
      border: none;
    }
    
    .dropdown {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #f9f9f9;
      min-width: 160px;
      box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
      z-index: 1;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content a {
      color: black;
      padding: 12px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: block;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content a:hover {
      background-color: #f1f1f1
    }
    
    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
      display: block;
    }
    
    .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
      background-color: #3e8e41;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.0/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML" type="text/javascript"></script>

<body>

  <h2>Hoverable Dropdown</h2>
  <p>Move the mouse over the button to open the dropdown menu.</p>

  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <br/><math><mi>a</mi><mo>≠</mo><mn>0</mn></math><math><mi>a</mi><mo>≠</mo><mn>0</mn></math>
  <br/><math><mi>a</mi><mo>≠</mo><mn>0</mn></math><math><mi>a</mi><mo>≠</mo><mn>0</mn></math>
  <br/><math><mi>a</mi><mo>≠</mo><mn>0</mn></math><math><mi>a</mi><mo>≠</mo><mn>0</mn></math>

</body>

</html>
```

You can find full example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ewadb1yq/1/)

Why does it happen? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `z-index:1` to your `.dropdown` style, and that should take care of it. The MathJax output below the button is overlapping the button slightly, so using `z-index`, you can raise the button on top of it.

Answer (score 1):

You can add helper, using `:before` to fill the gap on hover:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>
    .dropbtn {
      background-color: #4CAF50;
      color: white;
      padding: 16px;
      font-size: 16px;
      border: none;
    }
    
    .dropdown {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    
    .dropdown:hover:before{
      content:'';
      position: absolute;
      top:0;
      left:0;
      bottom:-25px;
      right:0;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #f9f9f9;
      min-width: 160px;
      box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
      z-index: 1;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content a {
      color: black;
      padding: 12px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: block;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content a:hover {
      background-color: #f1f1f1
    }
    
    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
      display: block;
    }
    
    .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
      background-color: #3e8e41;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.0/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML" type="text/javascript"></script>

<body>

  <h2>Hoverable Dropdown</h2>
  <p>Move the mouse over the button to open the dropdown menu.</p>

  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <br/><math><mi>a</mi><mo>≠</mo><mn>0</mn></math><math><mi>a</mi><mo>≠</mo><mn>0</mn></math>
  <br/><math><mi>a</mi><mo>≠</mo><mn>0</mn></math><math><mi>a</mi><mo>≠</mo><mn>0</mn></math>
  <br/><math><mi>a</mi><mo>≠</mo><mn>0</mn></math><math><mi>a</mi><mo>≠</mo><mn>0</mn></math>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But your code does not fix my issue. Menu still disappear when I try to move cursor to it's elements